# Loading default value in a dropdown and calling onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i have following dropdown

```
<div class="fcolumn">
    <label class="text" for="o_Id">Months:</label>
    <select class="textMonths" id="o_Id" name="periodName" >
        <option value="000">Select Period--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In the following jquery, first it loads fnLoadP() in a drop down list. Than as a default I am loading one of the values in drop down which is '10'. It loads too as default value. But it should be executing  $("#o_Id").change..  which it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sProfileUserId = null;

    $("#o_Id").change(function () {
        //----
    });

    fnLoadP();

    $("select[name='pName']").val('10');      
});
});
```

Basically my goal is. After dropdown values are loaded,  to load '10' as default value and call onchange event in the dom. Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: what does jquery-ui have to do with this?

Comment: The `change` event is only triggered when changing a value with the UI, not when changing it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below line into the fnLoadP();

```
$("select[name='pName']").val('10');
```

I can help you more on this, if you shared  fnLoadP(); code.